# How does MySQL manage a delete then select of the same row within a transaction

Tags: mysql

Considering MySQL ver 5.7.
Take the following example:

```
Begin Transaction
Delete from payments where id = 1
Select from payments where id = 1
End Transaction
```

In such a scenario should I expect the select statement to return no rows, since I've just deleted that row?  Or will it still return a row because the transaction has not yet been committed?

And if the select does not return a row, then can I assume that any cascade deletes on child tables are also safely deleted before I do my select?

(To answer the inevitable question of "why would you do this?" the answer is simply that I'm hoping to re-use the same script in multiple different scenarios, so I want to know if it's safe to do so or if I have to write separate scripts.  In one scenario the delete will execute, in another it will not.)

Comment: What "transaction_isolation" mode are you running with?

Comment: Not sure how I would know.  Does this make a difference?

Comment: I don't know if the setting would change things.  (It's on my list of things to experiment with _someday_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the `SELECT` statement is concerned, the `id = 1` row is gone. There might be argument as to whether the physical storage still contains the bits of the data pertaining to the deleted row at the time of the `SELECT`, but in terms of access to that data, the select will (should) return nothing.